# Как получить доступ к элементу массива из другого класса?

Tags: java

Коллеги, приветствую.

У меня стоит задача в построении морского боя. Я начинающий и не понимаю ошибку и даже найти ее решения не могу.

Есть метод, в нем игрок указывает куда будет стрелять:

```
public void doShoot() {
    turnScanner =new Scanner(System.in);
    shoot=new Shoot();
    System.out.println("Куда будем стрелять? Введите номер позиции и нажми Enter");
    x= turnScanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Вы стреляли в x="+ x);
    shoot.doShoot();
}
```

Этот метод, преобразует ранее созданный двумерный массив в одномерный, чтобы игрок мог указать лишь 1 позицию. Например А1 будет 1, А2=2 и так далее.

```
public void rewriteArray(){
    for (int k=0;k<counts; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < fieldSize[i].length; j++) {
               newFieldSize[k]=fieldSize[i][j];
               System.out.print(newFieldSize[k]);
               k++;
           }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Вот класс, в котором я создаю поля:

```
public class Field {
    Scanner stepScanner;
    Scanner turnScanner;
    int x;
    int y;
    int counts;
    int[][] fieldSize;
    int[] newFieldSize;

    public  Field(){
        counts=x*y;
        newFieldSize=new int[counts];
        stepScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public int getNewFieldSize(int x) {
        System.out.println(newFieldSize[x]);
        return newFieldSize[x];
    }
}
```

В этом классе, я делаю выстрел по кораблю:

```
public class Shoot {
    Field fields;

    public void doShoot() {
        fields=new Field();
        fields.getNewFieldSize(0);
    }
}
```

Собственно при компиляции, у меня возникает ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at ru.mega.Field.getNewFieldSize(Field.java:23)
at ru.mega.Shoot.doShoot(Shoot.java:14)
at ru.mega.Player.doShoot(Player.java:50)
at ru.mega.Main.main(Main.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Я понимаю, что можно сделать выстрел в классе Field и мороки не будет.  А может даже и через ArrayList можно будет это сделать ( не пробовал и не хочу, так как хочу отработать все на примитивах сначала).

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с этим.

Как сделать так, чтобы в классе Field мой массив newFieldSize получал значения из метода rewriteArray ( из этого же класса) и передавал их в класс Shoot?

Спасибо.

Comment: Здесь ошибка в строке в процедуре `getNewFieldSize` `newFieldSize[x]` , или даже в fields.getNewFieldSize(0); Логика не понятна, вы запрашиваете елемент с номером ноль, но массив *newFieldSize* у вас **пустой**. Поэтому возникает исключение. Вам нужно создать массив, до вызова ф-ции `doShoot` как минимум, либо пересмотреть логику алгоритма.

Comment: `System.out.println("Вы стреляли в x="+ x);
    shoot.doShoot();`

вот тут лучше сделать проверку  и выдать ошибку, мол вы указали некорректные координаты. повторите снова...

Comment: В том то и проблема. Как сделать так, чтобы массив в классе Shoot уже при создании объекта был инициализированным? Я не пойму просто ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсказали, что надо было создавать объекты в Main и только. В итоге в классе Player и Shoot мне надо создать сеттеры/геттеры которые бы возвращали бы значения куда мне нужно.

Всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Что будет если в массиве у вас два элемента с индексами `[0]` и `[1]`, а вы пытаетесь получить элемент с индексом `[2]`? произойдет исключение: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Тоже самое и у вас:

```
public int getNewFieldSize(int x) {
        System.out.println(newFieldSize[x]);
        return newFieldSize[x];
    }
```

Какое значение по вашему должен вернуть этот метод?

Comment: В данному случае, newFieldSize является одномерным массивом для fieldSize.
то есть были позиции 
11 12 13
21 22 23

а стали 
1 2 3
4 5 6

В итоге, обращаясь к элементу с индексом 2, я должен попасть на элемент массива 3, который в свою очередь приведет нас к 13.

Comment: newFieldSize у вас вообще пустой, лучше тогда получить значение из fieldSize.
И лучше не применять слово 'new' как часть названия, только в редких случаях возможно.

Comment: Хорошо, а как его сделать не пустым? )
Просто, если я сразу сделать
int[] newFieldSize= new int[10];
и если я заполню нулями, то все равно не то, мне нужно чтобы в классе Field  заполнилась матрица циферками, а из них я уже буду смотреть что кораблик, а что нет.

Я не пойму, как сделать так, чтобы конструктор или метод передавал  заполненый уже массив.

Comment: Ок, Какая информация из двумерного массива должна быть в одномерном?

Comment: Я ж чуть выше написал)

Comment: Игрок сам задает размеры поля, например 5 на 9.
Откуда у нас получается х=5, у=9.
Эти данные заносятся в двумерный массив fieldSize[x][y].
Затем, я хочу обработать данные через switch. Игрок говорит, стреляю в x=1,y=3. Но switch, насколько я знаю, не умеет обрабатывать запросы типа
    switch (fields.newFieldSize[x][y])
В следствие этого, я создаю одномерный массив newFieldSize, в котором должны храниться значения полученные с помощью метода public void rewriteArray().

Comment: Попробуй так:
public class Shoot {
    Field field = new Field();

    public void doShoot() {
        field.rewriteArray();
        field.getNewFieldSize(0);
    }
}

Comment: К сожалению, снова появились ошибки:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at ru.mega.Field.getNewFieldSize(Field.java:23)
 at ru.mega.Shoot.doShoot(Shoot.java:15)
 at ru.mega.Player.doShoot(Player.java:50)
 at ru.mega.Main.main(Main.java:30)

Comment: Проверьте почему метод rewriteArray ничего не добавляет в массив newFieldSize, ошибка в этом

Comment: В классе Field все норм, массивы оба заполнены. Проблема в том, что я передать значения массивов в другой класс не могу. Я даже делал просто System.out.print() всех элементов массива, но... передать не могу в другой класс

Comment: Ага, вот тут поправка:

`public void rewriteArray(){
        for (int k=0;k<counts; k++)
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { ...}}`
У меня почему-то counts=0, хотя, в конструкторе он определен как counts=x*y;

Comment: Какое значение у примитива объявленном в классе напр. int x;? Подумайте сами.

Поэтому counts=x*y //0

Можете объявить эти филды в объявлении класса, или передавать их в констрокторе

Comment: У меня в x и y передаюся значения типа x= stepScanner.nextInt();
 Но это выполняется в методах. Разве можно просто так в классе это сделать, чтобы в методе просто написать как-то, x и пользователь должен будет внести значение в консоль?

Comment: Перенесите логику по определению x и у в конструктор класса Field. 1. определяется x; 2. определяется y; 3. вычисляется count на основании x и y.